# Locals in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have a local statement that I need to create it on the locals:

`location = local.basic["local"].region`

How this statement is translated in locals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***It will be something like below :***

```
locals {
  basic={
    local={
      region="eastus"
    }
  }
}
output "name" {
  value=local.basic["local"].region
}
```

**Output:**

[image]